# How to Read Xml data using codeigniter?

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, curl, codeigniter-2

I want to read xml data using curl in codeigniter. I have create a helper file which will read data from following url: http://www.ekidata.jp/api/l/11302.xml but problem is that i cannot read the data from this url. plz help
Here is my helper file structure:

```
if (!function_exists('ekidata')) {

function ekidata($type, $code)
{

    $apiurl = 'http://www.ekidata.jp/api/'.$type.'/'.$code.'.xml';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiurl);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
    if ($type == 'l') {
        return $xml;    
    } else {

    }
}
```

}

Here is my controller:

```
function ekidatatest()
{
    $this->load->view('ekidatatest');
}
```

Here is my view:

```
<?php echo ekidata('l', 11302);?>
```

Comment: Your code contains no error handling and the output format is most likely standing in the way to display XML encoded information and/or plain text values. Please take care that "but problem is that i cannot read the data from this url" is not a well described problem so your question invites to guessing. However Stackoverflow is a Q&A site about programming questions and less asking for opinions and guesses. Perhaps you're able to improve your question an pin-point the first line of code which already does something unexpected in your opinion and you can explain what you expected instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code and it works ok, the only issue i see is that you are tryin to echo an object (the returned XML variable), try:

`print_r (ekidata('l', 11302));`

and you should see all the xml object from the file, then you can loop on the object and get the data you need. So if you want the first station name you can get it like this:

```
$r = ekidata('l', 11302);
echo $r->station[0]->station_name;
```

and to loop on all stations:

```
foreach($r->station as $station) {
    echo $station->station_name.'<br/>';

 }
```